# Spring boot Restful API: Simple authentication

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing Restful API endpoints using Spring boot. I want to create login/logout functionality. I don't want to use Spring boot default login page.

From my understanding, a simple and secure way to do so, is:

1. Client provides server with username and password
2. Server sends back an authentication code, which user can use for subsequent calls to the API endpoints
3. The authentication code is valid until users logs out/a certain amount of time passes

Is there any conventional name for this method of authentication ?

I don't want to use Spring boot login page. Does Spring boot have any other default implementation for this authentication method ? If yes, where does it store the authentication code. Does it store in the memory ?

Comment: "I don't want to use Spring boot login page." --You haven't explained *why*. What about it are you wanting to replace?

Comment: I'm implementing restful api. There is no UI for it.

Comment: Then perhaps you're looking for Spring Security OAuth2 with password grant?

Comment: I'm not planning to use any third party for authentication. No facebook, twitter, etc. authentication is needed. It's just a simple login/logout between a server and a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stateless, token-based authentication is what you're looking for.
Json Web Tokens (JWT) is one implementation of that.

I wrote a tutorial about setting up JWT in SpringBoot for use with Angular. It's too long to include here - it's a two-parter, and the second part, dealing with JWT is at http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part2

If you want the first part, it's at http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1

Comment: I found this article helpful, too:
https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same question before. Since you are implementing a Rest API, it should be stateless by default, so that means you should authenticate yourself every time when you want to request some API. If you prefer this way, maybe try to have some CAS system which you can use to perform the authentication. This is almost the same as what you described in the question. (Here is a [post](https://simonlzn.github.io/2016/11/20/CAS-with-Spring-Security.html) of simplified CAS from my blog).

Otherwise, you can also consider having an entry point or maybe proxy in front of your Rest service, in this proxy you can set a token for the client based on the credentials it provides, then ask the client to send this token along with the request. Set an expire time for the token and invalidate after that time.

I don't think there is any existing implementation for this in Spring boot, but for both CAS and token based request, you can use Spring Security for part of the features, e.g. TokenBasedAuthentication is already implemented in Spring Security

Comment: How is it different from JWT mentioned in the other answer ?

Comment: When I posted my answer, his was not there yet:) , for the token based solution, I think they are exactly the same.